# Amadeus API Authentication on a VueJS Application

Tags: vue.js, amadeus

In the previous sandbox I was able to use the flight search tool directly within my vue js app. I was able to do this by passing the API key in a string. Since the changeover to the self service API I am at a complete loss on how to implement the curl command in order to generate a token to use in my app. I have read the developer guide and it is spartan to say the least. It doesn't provide any steps on how to incorporate this in to any existing app. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [authorization guide](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/developer-guides/blob/master/guides/authorization.md)? The new version of the Amadeus API program implements the standard oauth2 process which is more secure than the API Key in the URL.

You have a curl example in the guide and examples in different languages.
You can check the [GitHub organization](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/) as well to find more examples and different SDKs.